# AWS Elastic Beanstalk internal server error after stripe payment

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, security, stripe-payments

I made a stripe payment on my new webpage hosted by aws. After that the page shut down (it always returns error 500: internal server error. I tried a lot of things, also shutting down the instance and rebooting it. It still returns error 500. I'm not very experienced in this topic so I don't know what information you may need so feel free to ask. I would be very happy if someone could help me to get my webpage back running normally. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This could be any number of things and debugging it will require a great deal more detail. You should start by reviewing your server logs to see what is causing that 500 error.

You also need to more clearly describe the flow being used here. Is this a redirect to your site from eg Stripe Checkout? Is this an API call from your own app to your own backend?

Comment: The log says: "AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/public/.env" and it was a redirect from stripe checkout to my site but now the error 500 pops up anywhere. I guess it is a configuration issue. Do you know what configurations i need to make in order to use stripe within aws?

Comment: Again this could be anything -- "AWS" has many different services that can be configured effectively infinite ways. What specifically are you trying to do? Host a page for Checkout redirects? Do you use a `.env` file to store secrets? It seems unexpected that you'd place that in a `/public` directory, as typical usage with secret would seemingly be exposed here.

Comment: I just wanted to use stripe to make transactions between two users of the page. I am using a .env file but not to store secrets. I just don't really understand where the error comes from as I can't find any other issues in the logs.

Comment: Maybe it is also worth to mention that only one page is down. The other pages work.